# Iterating through columns for separate plots in Python

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

I am extremely new to coding, so I appreciate any help I can get. 
I have a large data file that I want to create multiple plots for where the first column is the x axis for all of them. The code would ideally then iterate through all the columns with each respectively being the new y axis. I included my code for the individual plots, but want to create a loop to do it for all the columns.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = df[:,0]
col_1= df[:,1]
plt.plot(X,col_1)
plt.show()

col_2= df[:,2]
plt.plot(X,col_2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

Pandas will iterate over all the columns for you. Simply place the x column in the index and then just make a call to plot with your dataframe. Pandas uses the index as the x-axis There is no need to directly use matplotlib. Here is some fake data with a plot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5), columns=['x', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4'])
df = df.sort_values('x')

          x        y1        y2        y3        y4
9  0.262202  0.417279  0.075722  0.547804  0.599150
5  0.314894  0.611873  0.880390  0.282140  0.513770
8  0.406541  0.933734  0.879495  0.500626  0.527526
2  0.407636  0.550611  0.646449  0.635693  0.807088
1  0.437580  0.194937  0.501611  0.949575  0.409130
4  0.497347  0.443345  0.658259  0.457635  0.851847
3  0.500726  0.569175  0.304910  0.151071  0.678991
6  0.547433  0.512125  0.539995  0.701858  0.358552
0  0.783461  0.649381  0.320577  0.107062  0.840443
7  0.793702  0.951807  0.938635  0.526010  0.098321

df.set_index('x').plot(subplots=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! If I don't have the x axis header as 'x' what would I use in the set_index input? It is not very feasible to add the header with x, y1, y2, etc either because it is an unknown number of columns.

Comment: Use whatever the name of your first column is. It doesn't matter how many columns you have. You said you only have one x column correct?

Comment: All pandas dataframe columns have names. If they aren't specifically given then they are just the integers beginning from 0. Use `df.set_index(0)`

Comment: I get this error message :AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_index'

Comment: Please post a sample of your dataframe. Like the first few rows. Copy and paste the output of `print(df)`

Comment: Thats a numpy array not a pandas DataFrame. pass that numpy array to the dataframe constructor, `pd.DataFrame`

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through each column plotting it on its own subplot like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(df.shape[1]-1, sharex=True)
for i in range(df.shape[1]-1):
    ax[i].plot(df[:,0], df[:,i+1])

plt.show()
```

*edit*

I just realized your example was displaying 1 plot at a time. You could accomplish that like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(df.shape[1]-1):
    plt.plot(df[:,0], df[:,i+1])
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```